# Repair A/C Evaporator Coil

Tags: repair, leak, air-conditioning

The repair man says that leaks are most common in a place that is not repairable without using leak sealant, which would void a warranty and his company doesn't offer that service. My system is using R-22. I feel like I should call another company that is willing to try the sealant before replacing my system with one that uses R-401a. However, if the best option is to get a new system, I'd rather hurry up and get it over with.

Can someone tell me what is common practice for evaporator coil replacement?

Comment: The price of R-22 is only going to continue to climb. After the year 2020, r-22 will no longer be produced.  Which will likely cause the price of the refrigerant to skyrocket. If you can't stop the leak, recharging the system will quickly bypass the cost of replacing the system. If you have the funds to replace the system, it might be a good time to do so.

Comment: @tester the tech said the leak is in one of the u-joints. Is that repairable?

Comment: Depending on the equipment, it may be possible to convert the system to a different type of refrigerant.

Comment: If I were you, I'd buy a leak kit and do it myself. Then have them come and recharge the system, or as you say, find someone who will do both. What good is a warranty if you're going to replace it anyway? When it fails again, it's time to think about replacing it. -It is not economically advisable to pay someone to physically repair a failed u-joint.

Comment: @Mazura Brazing refrigerant lines is not typically a DIY job, especially on systems with ozone damaging refrigerants.

Comment: @Tester101, I meant doing the leak kit themselves. Aside from the certifications required, you'd need a few thousand dollars worth of equipment to actually work on it.

Comment: By the time you pay for the can of fix-a-flat (whatever that costs), the $100+ per pound of R-22 to charge the system, and whatever the technician charges in labor. You're probably looking at a $500 - $1000 experiment. How much are they quoting to upgrade the system?

Comment: $2k for just a new evap coil + the recharge, or $4k-$6k for a complete system using 401a.